# Tools to analyse weaknesses based on Lichess history

Tags: analysis, training, lichess, opening-traps

Are there any tools that can find weaknesses in your games based on your Lichess history (eg, you often play a particularly bad line in a certain opening, or often fall for a certain trap), and then perhaps offers training to help rectify it?

Comment: You can try to figure some things out yourself using the chess insights feature. (on your profile there should be a button that leads you there I think) There you can look at various stats, including for instance in which openings you score well or poorly.

Comment: Use the unmatchable power of the human mind!

Comment: @koedem Yes, I do this, but it's a fairly blunt instrument. Knowing "you often lose against opening X" is one thing, but "you often lose against opening X because you frequently push the f pawn or keep choosing this bad line. Here, practice a much better response to 4..Ng4 instead" is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @David I believe the human mind was definitively out-matched by computers in 1997, but thank you.

Comment: Yes, the insights definitely don't give you all the answers, I'm just saying they can help you were to look. E.g. if you score poorly in some opening you might want to have a look at some of those games and see what went wrong. In the end, finding and fixing ones weaknesses is hard.

Comment: @SteveBennett playing chess is a completely different skill from the one you are asking for in your question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @David ?

Comment: @SteveBennett Just because computers are better than humans at chess, it doesn't mean they are etter at explaining why you make mistakes at chess

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Certainly. AimChess does exactly that. You may want to pay for it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that AimChess is a paid service that seeks to give you customized answers using some fancy machine learning algorithms and normal engine play.

However, I think you can recreate most of this yourself from some combination of openingtree.com, the default opening book, and lichess insights. Specifically, I'd first look at openingtree and your insights to see which openings you struggle with. Within those openings, see if there are lines you are going for that are suboptimal by comparing your play against the masters database. Are you comfortable with the resulting positions you're getting, even if they are "best" play? If not, you should look at a collection of master games from those positions and see if you can guess the move. If you are aware of what to do but just don't like the positions, maybe you should look at different move orders that avoid the openings themselves.

Lichess insights on its own can also show you if you're too often moving your queen in specific openings, or if you are too rash in pawn moves, but nothing will ultimately beat you just putting in the time and energy to explore options within specific openings and see what typical plans players much higher rated than you attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Lichess saves all chess games I played, and anybody can go to my profile page, filter on the games I lost, and see which openings I played there. Because I analyze a lot of my games, you can see where it went wrong.

Tool: lichess database and your own time

O jea, you can also see timing there, so you can also see in what time I played my blunders (rapid, correspondense, unlimited, ...)